# HPP Incorrect hash

Tags: realex-payments-api, global-payments-api

I send a request to the sandbox to "Pay By Link".
URL: `https://pay.sandbox.realexpayments.com/pay`

I get an error in response.
`{"errors":[{"resultCode":508,"internalErrorCode":61000,"errorMessage":"Incorrect hash. Please check your code and the Developers Documentation."}]}`

The hash is calculated correctly (the values obtained through the SDK and calculated manually are the same).
This is possible with the wrong shared secret.

I use the values of the MerchantId and the SharedSecret in my account on the https://developer.globalpay.com/gp_api_credentials/
(My Account->Ecomm API Credentials->Sandbox Credentials)

1. How to fix the error?
2. Can i change the "Ecomm API Credentials->Sandbox Credentials" ?

Answer (score 0):

The server reply is often completely wrong, so don't believe the error message it tells you. Remove all optional config field values (such as `CardStorageEnabled`) and try again. Then it should work, and after that you can re-enable the optional fields one by one to see which one causes the error.